# Как возвращать ответ от Jq ajax на php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
    $("#LogIn").click(function(){
        var textLogin = $("#Login").val();
        var textPass = $("#Pass").val();
        var responce;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/login.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                login: textLogin,
                pass: textPass
            },
            success: function(res){
                responce = res;
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('failure');
            }
        });
        alert(responce);
    });

 <?php
 echo "dasdasd";
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, если ответ {"event":"success"}, то Вы можете обработать ответ так:

```
$("#LogIn").click(function(){
        var textLogin = $("#Login").val();
        var textPass = $("#Pass").val();
        var responce;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/login.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                login: textLogin,
                pass: textPass
            },
            success: function(res){
                responce = JSON.parse(res);
                alert(res.event)
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('failure');
            }
        });
        alert(responce);
    });
```